# ListView default selected items mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-store-apps

I have ListView with dependency property for selecting more than one item. ListView sample code is here:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Test}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTemplate}"
          SelectionMode="Multiple" 
          multipleBind:SelectionChangedCommand.Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}">
</ListView>
```

It works properly but what I want is pre-select default items and I don't know How do it. Is it a possible? Please give me some hit.

Thanks

Comment: [Might be helpful](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412417/Managing-Multiple-selection-in-View-Model-NET-Metr)

Comment: It works now thanks. But pre-select items are not highlighted:-/